# Trouble with Displaying a Current Date and Time when Logged In on a UserForm when it Initialize

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have the following code:

```
  Set FindRow = Hoja6.Range("B:B").Find(What:=User, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAT:=xlPart)

  Me.UserLog.Text = "Best Guy."
  Me.RecentUserLog.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1).Value
  Me.LastUserLog.Value = FindRow.Offset(1, 1).Value
  End If
```

If i hide the two last lines, it works fine. But if i keep it like this, its says

`object variable or with object not set`

I tried Hoja6.Select (sheet6.Select) but still does not work. The purpose is to show the current date and time and the last log. The user variable is public, and it works when i open the userform, but now i changed a bit the filters by user, and having trouble solving this.

Comment: If there's no matching row then Find() returns `Nothing`, not a `Range` object.  You need to check for that in your code: don't just assume you got a match.

Comment: Your title seems unrelated to your question?

Comment: Alright, i will try that. I changed the title a bit so it's more understandable and related to the post

Comment: Now got it working, i changed yesterday the tables, so the username was different from the one the code was looking, so was my bad. I will post the new code below, but was the problem solve by changing the name on the table where FindRow was looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
    If User = "Guy" Then

        Me.UserLog.Text = "Guy."
        Set FindRow = Hoja6.Range("B:B").Find(What:="Big Guy", _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAT:=xlPart)

        If FindRow Is Nothing Then
            Me.RecentUserLog.Value = ""
            Me.LastUserLog.Value = ""
        Else
            Me.RecentUserLog.Value = FindRow.Offset(1, 0)
            Me.LastUserLog.Value = FindRow.Offset(2, 0)
        End If

     End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved as i changed on the table where the values are stored and forgot that i changed the username for their real name, so the FindRow was never finding that value, which i was sure it was correct, so my bad. Yet, i added the code provided on the comments before so if this happens again, i have it backed up.

```
 If User = "Guy" Then
 Set FindRow = Hoja6.Range("B:B").Find(What:="Big Guy", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAT:=xlPart)

 Me.UserLog.Text = "Guy."
 Me.RecentUserLog.Value = FindRow.Offset(1, 0)
 Me.LastUserLog.Value = FindRow.Offset(2, 0)

 ElseIf FindRow Is Nothing Then
 Me.UserLog.Text = "Guy."
 Me.RecentUserLog.Value = ""
 Me.LastUserLog.Value = ""
 End If
```

Comment: You need to test FindRow Is Nothing before the statement Me.RecentUserLog.Value = FindRow.Offset(1, 0)